# Make SSL certificate work identically in desktop and mobile browser

Tags: browser, ssl, certificate, mobile-phone

When browsing my SSL-secured site via desktop\laptop the certificate chain is OK and trusted

[image: Desktop browser]
[image: Certificate]

I have checked [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)  and found that certificate chain is incomplete (additional intermediate certificate is required).
[image: SSL check]

However looks like desktop\laptop browsers are able to restore the chain and download required certificates.

But when switching to mobile browsers (especially Android) there are the following errors:

[image: Mobile Firefox]

[image: Mobile Android]

Note that on iOS (iPhone\iPad) no security warnings is present and site is shown as "green" with  keylock icon.

[image: iPad browser]

What is the correct way to mitigate the mobile browser's warnings?
Maybe re-issue the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take the investigation work you've already done at face value, it sounds like your Android devices don't already trust the intermediate CA that issued the server cert in question, and they don't want to just download and start trusting that intermediate CA cert.

It sounds like you have two choices:

1. Pre-install that intermediate CA cert, and mark it as trusted, on all your Android devices.
2. Buy a different server cert that's issued by a CA that all your devices already trust.

I suppose it's possible that those Android devices might accept the intermediate CA cert if it was offered as part of the cert chain that the web server sends at the start of the TLS negotiation. You might want to make sure that your web server has a copy of the intermediate CA cert installed, and that it's offering it as part of the TLS negotiation.

Comment: I hope you understand the impossibility of pre-installing intermediate certificate on all end-user devices, especially when we're planning go live :)  However maybe you can advise what exactly should i tell to CA like thawte so they will issue a new certificate without intermediate cert (or with global-trusted intermediate cert) as i am unaware of the correct way?

Comment: @Sergey Haha, yes. I wasn't sure this was a public website. I've seen people buy public certs for internal websites, so it was within the realm of possibility that pushing a new cert to all your company's mobile devices would be a solution. I think you should tell Thawte about your intermediate CA problem on Android and ask them what they recommend as a solution. They probably know exactly which Android versions (and phone-vendor-distributions) already trust their intermediate CA, and which ones don't. They can probably tell you better than I can what you need to do to fix this.

Comment: Update: the latest mobile versions of Safari\Chrome and IE (on Windows Phone) are able to retrieve the full chain. Default Android browser and Firefox on Android - unable.